# How to delete Pods or restart containers which are targets of kubectl attach/exec?

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to automatically restart any container which is the target of kubectl exec/kubectl attach after the session is closed. Is this currently possible?

Comment: Please describe your question with more details.

Comment: What isn't clear? If I run `kubectl exec <pod name> -c <container name>`, I want `<container name>` to restart when I exit the exec session.

Comment: Any specific reason for container restart?

Comment: There is something wrong with your question... You can't restart a container inside a pod, you need to restart the entire pod. Other than this, do you need to kubectl exec for something specific inside the pod? or is it just testing configuration modification and you want the pod to go back to default configuration after you finish your actions?

Comment: I want to erase any manual changes made after troubleshooting via kubectl exec, either via container restart or Pod deletion.

Answer (score 0):

In K8s, Pod (not container) is the smallest unit in terms of operation.

So the workaround is to restart entire pod after the session.

Simple command concatenation with logical *AND* will work for your task, i.e.

`kubectl exec -it webserver-1 bash && kubectl delete pod webserver-1`

Once you exit the pod session second part of the command will be executed - removing a pod and a scheduler will spin up a new pod for you (if that was a part of replica set).

Comment: I know I can delete the pod manually after I exec into it. I'm looking for a way to force it to happen automatically. For context, I run a Kubernetes-based PaaS at my work and our security team would like to automatically erase any container or Pod that's been tampered with.

Comment: And technically, you can do operations at the container level if you control the underlying Node. We have components on our cluster that integrate with the underlying container runtimes to operate on individual containers.

Comment: @DharmaBellamkonda you are right, I have updated my post, stating that this is a workaround and not a straight solution, which doesn't seem feasible for me.